# How to change direction in which a control resizes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, label

I'm making an application in VB.NET and I have a control (a label to be specific) and it's been set to auto size based on the texts in it. Currently, the label box resizes to the left and down:

> [Label] ->
>   |
>   v

I want the label to resize to the right and down:

> <-[Label]
>   |
>   v

How would I do this?

Edit: the label display's the windows account name. It's aligned to the right side of the window, so that's why the text must be autosized and expand to the left rather then the right.

Comment: have you try my answer ?

Comment: I still want the textbox to auto resize, but when it auto resizes, it should expand/decrease to the left and down, not right and down. This works for my application, but it's not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: since the label is autosized, you can't resize it .. at least that what I knew ..

Comment: WinForms, WPF, or something else?

Comment: @user1877499 .. what's the autosize purpose in your case ? .. autosize will give you no padding for the text ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to adjust the location according to the change in size.  Here's some code that will do that.    I used the Tag property to hold he current size before the resize. then in the Resize event handler adjusted the location.  Whenever the label's text is changed the tag gets the size.  When the resize is called the size has changed and comparing the 2 will tell us how much to change the location.  since the defaul autosize operation is already down I didn't change that.

```
Private Sub Label1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.TextChanged
    Label1.Tag = Label1.Size
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Resize(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Resize
    Dim TempSize As New Size(New Point(0))
    If Label1.Tag Is Nothing Then Label1.Tag = Label1.Size
    TempSize = DirectCast(Label1.Tag, Size)
    Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X - (Label1.Size.Width - TempSize.Width), Label1.Location.Y)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the label to resize to the right and down:

Set label's property

Autosize = False
TextAlign = TopRight